# Downloading previous purchases in iTunes says "Buy"

Tags: icloud, music, itunes

I'm trying to download previous iTunes purchases to a computer.  The following warning comes up.

[image: iTunes Buy]

I know how to deal with authorizing the computer, but what I'm concerned about is the "Buy" button.  I was under the impression I could download previous purchases free of charge.  What's going to happen when I click "Buy" on a previous purchase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really purchased it, it will show buy and then tell you it's free since you already bought it. As long as you didn't mistake a newer version of the song you can "buy" again for free. There is a report a problem link if you do accidentally re-buy substantially the same item and I wouldn't hesitate to ask for a refund when the storekeeper doesn't make it easier to know if it's a re-download or a buy.